# is it possible to read mp3 id3 tags in php using ffmpeg? if so then how?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, id3

Hi i have a few mp3 files in my server which constantly change and i need the mp3 id3 tags for people to know what song is being played at the moment preferably via php . I am a complete noob at this so any help is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there are several possibilities, I was always a fan of using pipes.
ffprobe should be included in ffmpeg.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("ffprobe -print_format json -show_entries stream=codec_name:format -select_streams a:0 -v quiet test.mp3");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Output:

```
    {
        "programs": [

        ],
        "streams": [
            {
                "codec_name": "mp3"
            }
        ],
        "format": {
            "filename": "test.mp3",
            "nb_streams": 1,
            "nb_programs": 0,
            "format_name": "mp3",
            "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration": "303.755813",
            "size": "9721021",
            "bit_rate": "256021",
            "probe_score": 51,
            "tags": {
                "title": "Pictures Of Home",
                "artist": "Deep Purple",
                "album": "Machine Head",
                "date": "1972",
                "track": "3",
                "genre": "Rock"
            }
        }
    }
```

Use json_decode to convert it into an assoicative array.

Comment: Question mate.. 
$output = shell_exec("ffprobe -print_format json -show_entries stream=codec_name:format -select_streams a:0 -v quiet test.mp3");
here test.mp3 could it be a url instead? or does it have to be a local directory address?

Comment: $output = shell_exec("ffprobe -print_format json -show_entries stream=codec_name:format -select_streams a:0 -v quiet 'http://mp3.stream.tb-group.fm/tb.mp3?'");
seems to work.

Comment: cool will try it out soon :) thank you so much ^_^